# Show that $\int\int_R f(x,y)dxdy\not=\int\int_R f(x,y) dydx$ For $R=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Show that $\int\int_R f(x,y)dxdy\not=\int\int_R f(x,y) dydx$ For $R=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$
>   Does this contradict Fubini's theorem?

I evaluated the integral to be $1/30$ and $-1/30$ which is apparently wrong.

Obviously the answer is supposed to be no but I don't really understand why.

Comment: If the result is true, you have to compute both integrals and show that they are different. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I evaluated it to be $1/30$ and $-1/30$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've calculated the two iterated integrals, and shown them to be different. What does Fubini's theorem say?

> The iterated integrals $\iint_A f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ and $\iint_A f(x,y)\,dy\,dx$ are equal, provided $f$ is absolutely integrable on $A$ - that is, $\iint_A |f(x,y)|\,dx\,dy$ is finite.

So, then, what about that condition? Does the integral of the absolute value converge?
$$\iint_R \frac{|x^2-y^2|}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\,dy \ge \iint_D \frac{|x^2-y^2|}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\,dy$$
where $D$ is the circular wedge $x^2+y^2< 1, x> 0, y>0$.
$$\iint_D \frac{|x^2-y^2|}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\,dy = \int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{|r^2\cos^2\theta-r^2\sin^2\theta|}{r^4}\cdot r\,d\theta\,dr$$
$$\iint_D \frac{|x^2-y^2|}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\,dy = \int_0^1 \frac1r\,dr\cdot \int_0^{\pi/2}|\cos(2\theta)|\,d\theta = \infty\cdot 1=\infty$$
We integrate the absolute value over $D$ with polar coordinates, and get $\infty$ that way. Our function $f$ is not absolutely integrable over $D$, and thus also not absolutely integrable over the larger square $R$. The preconditions of Fubini's theorem are not satisfied, and thus it's no surprise that the result doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Wikipedia article, there is your integral:

[Failure of Fubini's theorem for non-integrable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini's_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions).

Comment: So this function isn't integrable?